# Dependency injection and Tests

Tags: java, maven, junit, maven-surefire-plugin

I have a project that contains some tests, all it does is create a `test-jar` to be run by other projects. And it depends on a another artifact, let's call it artifact `X`

then there are multiple other projects that run the `test-jar`, using the `maven-surefire-plugin`

I have multiple implementations of artifact `X` and what I want to do is to be able to run those tests using the implementation that I want, not `X`

so for example:

in project `A` I want to run the tests using implementation `A`

in project `B` I want to run the tests using implementation `B`

this does not seems to be possible, because once the `test-jar` generated, it has the artifact `X` hard-coded in it

so I'm open to any other solutions

Edit :

extra information:

the pom file of the project generating the tests :

the part for generating the `test-jar`

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test-jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

the Artifact `X` dependency  :

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.conztanz</groupId>
        <artifactId>X</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
```

the pom file of one of the projects running the tests (project `A`):

```
    <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.15</version>
            <configuration>
                <dependenciesToScan>
                    <dependency>testJar</dependency>
                </dependenciesToScan>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Ideally what I want is do some thing that tells project `A` to `Override` artifact `X` with it's own implementation

I hope this makes more sense now

Comment: This is too abstract for me to get a handle on. Perhaps you could post the pertinent parts of various `pom.xml`'s, along with a simplified project structure?

Comment: okay i'll add some examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for the **scope** called `provided`.

The dependency would look like this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.conztanz</groupId>
    <artifactId>X</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

This tells Maven: "Hey, I need this to compile, but don't include it in the target output, because a container (or something) will provide the jar itself."

Comment: interesting, and how do you think other projects should provide their implementations of the X artifact ?

Comment: As a normal dependency, in their own `pom.xml`